# Error while configuring routes for WebAPI using MapHttpRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I had an ASP.Net web application with WebAPI that was built on Frameworks 4.0 and Visual Studio 2013.

Recently the system was formatted and Visual Studio 2015 was installed. Now I am unable to map the routes for the WebAPI in Global.asax file.

Below is the code I use to configure the routes.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I keep getting the error below.

*'RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'MapHttpRoute' and the best extension method overload 'HttpRouteCollectionExtensions.MapHttpRoute(HttpRouteCollection, string, string, object)' requires a receiver of type 'HttpRouteCollection'*

using Nuget package manager, I tried reinstalling ASP.NET MVC4 which was being used in the old code. I installed/reinstalled WebAPI, both the latest version and the old version that was being used before. I tried using System.Web.Http (again latest version and 4.something version that was used before) but i keep getting the above error. Please help!

Comment: Aint there a WebApiConfig class with Register(HttpConfiguration config) method inside which route is configured:
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Or if you specifically need to register routes in Global.asax, then:
 var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(....

Comment: I specifically need to register routes in Global.asax. I get the error 'The name 'GlobalConfiguration' does not exist in the current context.' I have a reference to System.Web.Http

Comment: The error is seen during Compile time. It is weird coz j have the required references!

Comment: Just to make sure, you are getting error at compile time, is it?

Comment: Do you have System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll referenced? Package - Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost

Comment: I have a reference to System.Web.Http.WebH‌​ost.dll.  I have tried the below code too. Though it compiles, My api's are not accesible through the path

RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(name: "DefaultApi", url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}");

When i try to access my WebAPI's using the path 'http://localhost:5556/api/RegionConfig/GetRegionConfigData' i get a 404 error. So that tells me that the routes are not configured right?

And thanks for taking time off to help. really appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121169/discussion-between-developer-and-alvin-saldanha).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check whether you have referred to System.Web.Http.WebH‌​ost.dll. In case issue still persists, then try reinstalling that package alone.
Package - Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost

Comment: reinstalling the webhost dll and restarting visual studio did the trick. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove below colored.

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            **//routes.MapHttpRoute(
            //    name: "DefaultApi",
            //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            //);**


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```